# Vector convert from raster hangs just before fully rendering in QGIS

Tags: raster-conversion

I've converted a raster to a vector layer (final size 200 megabytes), but when I load it in QGIS, it always hangs at about 95% and then takes sometimes 15 minutes to fully load. To be fair it does eventually load but is there a way to prevent it from getting stuck just before it fully loads?